actions/dependency-review-action issue while adding dual licensed packages for node project
I am trying to use  actions/dependency-review-action to only allow certain licensed dependencies to be merged in my project. One of my package turns out to be dual licensed. This is the snippet for the github actions workflow.
- name: Dependency Review
        uses: actions/dependency-review-action@v4.3.4
        with:
          fail-on-severity: high
          # Use comma-separated names to pass list arguments:
          allow-licenses: MIT, 0BSD, MIT AND Apache-2.0

But none of the licences are getting known
ISSUE
If i remove the MIT AND Apache-2.0 from the list and i add Apache-2.0 like this: MIT, 0BSD, Apache-2.0
This is what happens
Issue

"MIT AND Apache-2.0" isn't a valid SPDX-compliant identifier (per https://github.com/actions/dependency-review-action?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration -> https://spdx.org/licenses/). So when you include that it breaks things. When you only include valid identifiers, the output correctly tells you that @tableland/nonce isn't covered by one of those licenses. If you'd like to accept that one, maybe add it to allow-dependencies-licenses.
